# What is the meaning of lines here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In *Life (2017)* movie, David say this lines to Miranda in ISS spaceship:

> David: Your worry **lines** are showing
>
> Miranda: Yeah, well, I get paid by the **line**.

Is he referring to heart beat?

Answer (score 6):

*Worry lines* or *frown lines* are the permanent furrows seen in your brow when you often frown with worry. David's line means "I see from your face that you are worried".

Miranda jokes on this use of *line*. Her *paid by the line* means literally 'paid proportionally to the amount one writes', but she implies that she's paid to worry: taking care of worrying concerns is her job.